# How to make Ubuntu ISO bootable on a USB stick with OSX?

Tags: boot, usb, macosx

I have a Macbookpro and I'm planning to create a multiple boot. 
I've already created the necessary partitions and downloaded [image file](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=desktop&release=lts&bits=32)
(i386)

When I try to create a bootable USB stick from the ISO file, by means of "recovering" the disk image into the USB drive using Disk Image Utility, I get the following message:

> Could not validate source - corrupt image

The disk image can't be mounted in OSX either, I also get a similar message.

Is there any way to make a bootable Ubuntu USB stick from an ISO image in OSX?

Thanks

Comment: On step number 4 <br> sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m I entered the path and the it says no such file or directory.<br>
How can I enter the correct path? Could you give me some example about the path? <br> Thanks

Comment: Here are the official directions for this will which likely be kept up to date: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Answer (score 9):

The problem you're having is that is file you downloaded is corrupted, hence, not useful.

To solve this, [download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) Ubuntu again. Once done, try again. You can follow the [Official Guide for OSX](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx):

## 1: [Download Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download)

## 2: Convert the ISO file

Convert the .iso file to .img using the convert option of **hdiutil**

> hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img
> ~/path/to/ubuntu.iso

**Note**: OS X tends to put the .img ending on the output file automatically.

## 3: Determine the media to install

Run `diskutil list` to get the current devices. Insert your USB and the run again `diskutil list`. The new device its your USB.

## 4: Install into the USB

Unmount your device (not physically) with `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN` where N is your USB number and execute

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m
```

**Notes:**

- Using /dev/rdisk instead of /dev/disk may be faster
- If you see the error dd: Invalid number '1m', you are using GNU dd. Use the same command but replace bs=1m with bs=1M
- If you see the error dd: /dev/diskN: Resource busy, make sure the disk is not in use.Start the 'Disk Utility.app' and unmount (don't eject) the drive

## 5: Eject

Run `diskutil eject /dev/diskN` and remove your flash media when the command completes.

## 6: Boot

Restart your Mac and press alt/option key while the Mac is restarting to choose the USB stick.

Comment: Typo that's already fixed in the original doc: `OS X tends to put the .img ending` -> `OS X tends to put the .dmg ending`

Answer (score 2):

Step 4 needs to change:

```
unmountDisk /dev/diskN
```

should now be:

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN
```

For reference, see http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=107929, as this is what worked for me where as the instructions above did not. Using OSX v. 10.8.2

Answer (score -3):

It is very difficult to run ubuntu from a USB stick on a Mac. Here are some options:

1. Run Ubuntu from a USB stick on a PC
2. Install Ubuntu on a PC
3. Install Ubuntu on a Hard Drive on OSX.

But for booting Ubuntu on USB I have not succeeded in doing so.

Comment: [It is very possible.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) If you make a USB flash drive with Unetbootin, typically it is only bootable on a PC. If you make it with the technique on the website, it generally works fine. If you think I am mistaken, can you edit your question to provide more information?